# How to set opacity in TCPDF fill color?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I need to set opacity for bakcground color in TCPDF. 
The code below set whole the opacity of cell whole cell, I want only background opacity to be 0.5 and the text in cell is 1.

```
    $pdf->SetFillColor(150,204,255);
    $pdf->SetAlpha(0.5);
    $pdf->MultiCell($w, $h, "mytext", $border, $align, 1, $ln, $x, $y, $reseth, $stretch, $ishtml, $autopadding);
    $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
    $pdf->setFillColor(255,255,255);
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: İ could not, i simply print it wihout background :)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks :) i went with a workaround now that uses the rect() method, then resets alpha to 1, then prints the text.